# Divide by zero fix

Tags: python, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to do a calculation that sometimes involve dividing by zero, and I don't understand why my fix for it does not work.

Here's the relevant code:

```
try:
    ADX = (100 * (ema(14, difference))) / (PDI[-1] + NDI[-1])
    return ADX
except RuntimeWarning:
    ADX = ADX = (100 * (ema(14, difference))) / (PDI[-1] + NDI[-1] + 0.001)
    return ADX
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: A warning is just a warning, not an error. You should be aware that something might not work as expected. You can read https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html in order to control warnings.

Comment: don't divide by zero.  check if your denominator is going to be zero before dividing.  it looks like you want to add 0.001 if (PDI[-1] + NDI[-1]) = 0, you can add code to handle that situation before the exception is thrown.

Comment: @KlausD. Right, that is true. But I guess what I want to know is why my "except" code won't run. If I put a print statement in it it does not print.

Comment: provide your full code

Comment: Dividing by zero normally results in a `ZeroDivisionError` exception not a `RuntimeWarning`.

Comment: Not related to the question but why doing `ADX = ADX = ...` in the `except ` clause ? You can also not use `ADX` variable and use `return ...` directly